# find maximum without aggregate function

Tags: sql, max

I have the following schema for a table in SQL.

```
Owner (ownerid, name, phone, age)
```

I am asked to write a statement to find the oldest owner(s) in the database without using any aggregate function such as MAX. I'm also not allowed to use anything that is specific to any DBMS.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this homework or some interview question that is designed to show you how clever the interviewer is?

Comment: It is from a past exam paper of a course I'm taking at uni on Database Systems.

Comment: So it is a question to show you how clever your instructor is :)

Comment: What about standard SQL:2008  ORDER BY age DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `EXISTS` operator, which is standard on all SQL-compliant RDBMS:

```
SELECT age
FROM Owner o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Owner o2 WHERE o2.age > o1.age)
```

The idea behind this query is self-explanatory: the oldest owner is such an owner `o1` that there are no other owner `o2` such that `o2` is older than `o1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **NOT IN** and **JOIN** operator which is standard on all SQL-complaint RDMS.

```
select age from owner where age not in (select o2.age from owner as o1 JOIN owner as o2 ON o1.age > o2.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the ALL operator:

```
select o1.*
from "owner" o1
where age > all (select age 
                 from "owner" o2
                 where o2.ownerid <> o1.ownerid);
```

It essentially finds the owner where the age is greater than all age values except for the one we are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

This Version don't need anything like "not in", "all" or "not exists".

```
select
    o1.age
from
    Owner o1
left join 
    Owner o2
on
    o2.age > o1.age
where
    o2.age is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a few ways which I came up with after some thought.

Using TOP:

```
SELECT TOP 1 age
FROM Owner 
ORDER BY age DESC;
```

Using LIMIT:

```
SELECT age
FROM Owner
ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1
```

Using the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
SELECT x.age
FROM (SELECT age, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY age DESC) AS rank
      FROM Owner) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1;
```